Task runs fine using the airflow tasks test [dag_id] [task_id], but same thing doesnt work from the airflow UI
I have created an airflow server in localhost,but the dag doesnt complete the task when i run it from the airflow ui. It just keeps in running state and then 30 seconds later the scheduler heartbeat also stops.
But the same code runs perfectly fine as expected using airflow tasks test in cmd
When running from the ui, i only get this in the log and then it just hangs
2024-10-17T22:21:29.795+0530] {base.py:84} INFO - Retrieving connection 'api_posts'
Does not move forward after this line of log and runs forever, neither fails nor success.
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator
import json

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 10, 14),
}

dag = DAG(
    'my_dag_three',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
)

task_get_posts = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id="get_posts",
    http_conn_id="api_posts",
    endpoint="api/chat.postMessage",
    method="POST",
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Bearer #token",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data=json.dumps({
        "channel": "#channel",
        "text": "Hello from airflow"
    }),
    response_filter=lambda response: json.loads(response.text),
    log_response=True,
    dag=dag,
)

task_get_posts

The above is my code for the dag
I was expecting a success message. I have the right tokens and the right channel id. This api works fine using postman, but doesnt seem to work using the dag

If you navigate to that Airflow HTTP connection entry api_posts from the UI and click on the Test connection, does it succeed ?

I am not able to click on the test connection, looks like it is disabled.
